# How to run a shell script with input parameters in background from another script in bash

Tags: bash, shell, nohup

I have a script which reads 2 input parameters as given below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Input 1 : "
read a
echo -n "Input 2 : "
read b
nohup sh /path/script2.sh $a $b > custom-out.log &
```

The script is executing. But not exiting

It prints

```
nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout
```

and just hangs.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't hang.  The other script is being executed in the background.  Check out `custom-out.log`.

Comment: But, then, how to come back to the command prompt, without using ctrl+c?

Comment: You don't need to use Ctrl+c, simply press the `Enter` key or do `Ctrl+L`.

Comment: To capture everything in the log, you might want to use `nohup sh /path/script2.sh $a $b > custom-out.log 2>&1 &` It will then no longer say, `nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout`

Comment: What happens when you press Enter?

Comment: The suggestion by @mbratch works.... The control comes to the command prompt